# Variable number of bind variables in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

in Oracle, is it possible to have a dynamic number of bind variables in a EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dynamic SQL?

For example, in a given situation i might want to do something like:

```
execute immediate stmt using lv_name;
```

But, assuming that stmt is some string that i fetch from some configuration table, one day i might add an additional parameter and would have to recompile the PL/SQL unit to add another parameter, like:

```
execute immediate stmt using lv_name, lv_age;
```

...

is it possible in some way to do something like

```
execute immediate stmt using array_params[] ?
```

where array params is an array or some sort of structure in PL/SQL that i can handle dynamically? Or receive as a varchar2 parameter and split in some way into an array of tokens?

Thanks!

Comment: no you would need to use DBMS_SQL package

Comment: Dynamic SQL is intended to solve a certain set of use cases. It is not a magic bullet which allows us to replace our entire code base with a config table and a call to EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.  Dynamic SQL is hard to implement because it turns compilation errors into runtime errors: increased flexibility comes at the price of unreliability. Think about it this way: how would you **guarantee** that `array_params[0]` is always `lv_name` and `array_params[1]` is always `lv_age`?

Comment: What is the use case of such scenario? You may generate dynamic SQL that executes dynamic SQL with required number of bind variables. But I suspect that a SQL statement and a list of bind variables doesn't come from nothing. Then it would be better to perform binding in the application that generates this code.